# Firebase Database Failed to convert value of type java.util.ArrayList to String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I can not get my recycler view to work with the houses that I have on my firebase database. What I am trying to do is display all the houses on the starting activity but no luck for now. Here is what I have tried: 
Sorry for the many lines of code, but I wanted to show the complete code in order to explain it better.
[image: My database]

On the onStart() I try to populate the reyclerview:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseHouses;

    private String uid;
    private String email;
    private String username;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabaseHouses = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("HOUSES");

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_houses);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            signUser();
        }

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Houses, HousesViewHolder> mHousesRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Houses, HousesViewHolder>(
                Houses.class,
                R.layout.house_single,
                HousesViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseHouses
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(HousesViewHolder viewHolder, Houses house, int position) {
                viewHolder.setHouseName(house.getHouse_name());
            }
        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHousesRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    private static class HousesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;

        public HousesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }


        void setHouseName(String house_name) {
            TextView house_name_tv = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.single_house_name_tv);
            house_name_tv.setText(house_name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
            View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

            // Successfully signed in
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                final FirebaseUser signedUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.users)).child(signedUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                            Log.d("SignInProcess", "onDataChange: **Register");
                            uid = setNullToDefaultValue(signedUser.getUid());
                            email = setNullToDefaultValue(signedUser.getEmail());
                            User mUser = new User();
                            mUser.setUid(uid);
                            mUser.setEmail(email);
                            Map<String, Object> userMap = mUser.userToMap();
                            userMap.put("date", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                            mDatabase.child(getString(R.string.users)).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseUsernameActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Log.d("SignInProcess", "onDataChange: **Log In");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
                mDatabase.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
                Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "You Signed In!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                return;
            } else {
                // Sign in failed
                if (response == null) {
                    // User pressed back button
                    Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "User presses back", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    return;
                }

                if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                    Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "No Network", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    return;
                }

                if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                    Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "Unknown Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_log_out) {
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .signOut(MainActivity.this)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            if (currentUser == null) {
                                signUser();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void signUser() {
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme)
//                            .setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
                        .setAvailableProviders(
                                Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build()
                                ))
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    //Database Housekeeping
    public String setNullToDefaultValue(String s) {
        String defaultValue = "default_value";
        if (s == null)
            return defaultValue;
        return s;
    }
}
```

And here is the model class from which I use the getHouse_name() method:

```
/**
 * Created by nikos on 22/7/2017.
 */

public class Houses {
    private String availability;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String description;
    private Object fotos;
    private String hid;
    private String house_name;
    private String langitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String mainFoto;
    private String max_people;
    private String price;
    private String rating;
    private String postalCode;
    //Services
    private String aircondition;
    private String balcony;
    private String breakfast;
    private String cafe_bar_restaurant;
    private String child_keeping;
    private String clothes_laundry;
    private String conference_rooms;
    private String dinner;
    private String doctor_support;
    private String elevator;
    private String hair_dryer;
    private String in_room_safebox;
    private String iron_ironing_board;
    private String minibar;
    private String newspaper_delivery;
    private String parking;
    private String private_bath;
    private String reception_24;
    private String room_service;
    private String soundproof_walls;
    private String wifi;
    private String uid;
    private Object user_reviews;

    public Houses() {
    }

    public Houses(String availability, String city, String country, String description, Object fotos, String hid, String house_name, String langitude, String longitude, String mainFoto, String max_people, String price, String rating, String postalCode, String aircondition, String balcony, String breakfast, String cafe_bar_restaurant, String child_keeping, String clothes_laundry, String conference_rooms, String dinner, String doctor_support, String elevator, String hair_dryer, String in_room_safebox, String iron_ironing_board, String minibar, String newspaper_delivery, String parking, String private_bath, String reception_24, String room_service, String soundproof_walls, String wifi, String uid, Object user_reviews) {
        this.availability = availability;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.description = description;
        this.fotos = fotos;
        this.hid = hid;
        this.house_name = house_name;
        this.langitude = langitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.mainFoto = mainFoto;
        this.max_people = max_people;
        this.price = price;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.aircondition = aircondition;
        this.balcony = balcony;
        this.breakfast = breakfast;
        this.cafe_bar_restaurant = cafe_bar_restaurant;
        this.child_keeping = child_keeping;
        this.clothes_laundry = clothes_laundry;
        this.conference_rooms = conference_rooms;
        this.dinner = dinner;
        this.doctor_support = doctor_support;
        this.elevator = elevator;
        this.hair_dryer = hair_dryer;
        this.in_room_safebox = in_room_safebox;
        this.iron_ironing_board = iron_ironing_board;
        this.minibar = minibar;
        this.newspaper_delivery = newspaper_delivery;
        this.parking = parking;
        this.private_bath = private_bath;
        this.reception_24 = reception_24;
        this.room_service = room_service;
        this.soundproof_walls = soundproof_walls;
        this.wifi = wifi;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.user_reviews = user_reviews;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setAvailability(String availability) {
        this.availability = availability;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setFotos(Object fotos) {
        this.fotos = fotos;
    }

    public void setHid(String hid) {
        this.hid = hid;
    }

    public void setHouse_name(String house_name) {
        this.house_name = house_name;
    }

    public void setLangitude(String langitude) {
        this.langitude = langitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setMainFoto(String mainFoto) {
        this.mainFoto = mainFoto;
    }

    public void setMax_people(String max_people) {
        this.max_people = max_people;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public void setAircondition(String aircondition) {
        this.aircondition = aircondition;
    }

    public void setBalcony(String balcony) {
        this.balcony = balcony;
    }

    public void setBreakfast(String breakfast) {
        this.breakfast = breakfast;
    }

    public void setCafe_bar_restaurant(String cafe_bar_restaurant) {
        this.cafe_bar_restaurant = cafe_bar_restaurant;
    }

    public void setChild_keeping(String child_keeping) {
        this.child_keeping = child_keeping;
    }

    public void setClothes_laundry(String clothes_laundry) {
        this.clothes_laundry = clothes_laundry;
    }

    public void setConference_rooms(String conference_rooms) {
        this.conference_rooms = conference_rooms;
    }

    public void setDinner(String dinner) {
        this.dinner = dinner;
    }

    public void setDoctor_support(String doctor_support) {
        this.doctor_support = doctor_support;
    }

    public void setElevator(String elevator) {
        this.elevator = elevator;
    }

    public void setHair_dryer(String hair_dryer) {
        this.hair_dryer = hair_dryer;
    }

    public void setIn_room_safebox(String in_room_safebox) {
        this.in_room_safebox = in_room_safebox;
    }

    public void setIron_ironing_board(String iron_ironing_board) {
        this.iron_ironing_board = iron_ironing_board;
    }

    public void setMinibar(String minibar) {
        this.minibar = minibar;
    }

    public void setNewspaper_delivery(String newspaper_delivery) {
        this.newspaper_delivery = newspaper_delivery;
    }

    public void setParking(String parking) {
        this.parking = parking;
    }

    public void setPrivate_bath(String private_bath) {
        this.private_bath = private_bath;
    }

    public void setReception_24(String reception_24) {
        this.reception_24 = reception_24;
    }

    public void setRoom_service(String room_service) {
        this.room_service = room_service;
    }

    public void setSoundproof_walls(String soundproof_walls) {
        this.soundproof_walls = soundproof_walls;
    }

    public void setWifi(String wifi) {
        this.wifi = wifi;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public void setUser_reviews(Object user_reviews) {
        this.user_reviews = user_reviews;
    }

    public String getAvailability() {
        return availability;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Object getFotos() {
        return fotos;
    }

    public String getHid() {
        return hid;
    }

    public String getHouse_name() {
        return house_name;
    }

    public String getLangitude() {
        return langitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getMainFoto() {
        return mainFoto;
    }

    public String getMax_people() {
        return max_people;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public String getAircondition() {
        return aircondition;
    }

    public String getBalcony() {
        return balcony;
    }

    public String getBreakfast() {
        return breakfast;
    }

    public String getCafe_bar_restaurant() {
        return cafe_bar_restaurant;
    }

    public String getChild_keeping() {
        return child_keeping;
    }

    public String getClothes_laundry() {
        return clothes_laundry;
    }

    public String getConference_rooms() {
        return conference_rooms;
    }

    public String getDinner() {
        return dinner;
    }

    public String getDoctor_support() {
        return doctor_support;
    }

    public String getElevator() {
        return elevator;
    }

    public String getHair_dryer() {
        return hair_dryer;
    }

    public String getIn_room_safebox() {
        return in_room_safebox;
    }

    public String getIron_ironing_board() {
        return iron_ironing_board;
    }

    public String getMinibar() {
        return minibar;
    }

    public String getNewspaper_delivery() {
        return newspaper_delivery;
    }

    public String getParking() {
        return parking;
    }

    public String getPrivate_bath() {
        return private_bath;
    }

    public String getReception_24() {
        return reception_24;
    }

    public String getRoom_service() {
        return room_service;
    }

    public String getSoundproof_walls() {
        return soundproof_walls;
    }

    public String getWifi() {
        return wifi;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public Object getUser_reviews() {
        return user_reviews;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Houses{" +
                "availability='" + availability + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", fotos=" + fotos +
                ", hid='" + hid + '\'' +
                ", house_name='" + house_name + '\'' +
                ", langitude='" + langitude + '\'' +
                ", longitude='" + longitude + '\'' +
                ", mainFoto='" + mainFoto + '\'' +
                ", max_people='" + max_people + '\'' +
                ", price='" + price + '\'' +
                ", rating='" + rating + '\'' +
                ", postalCode='" + postalCode + '\'' +
                ", aircondition='" + aircondition + '\'' +
                ", balcony='" + balcony + '\'' +
                ", breakfast='" + breakfast + '\'' +
                ", cafe_bar_restaurant='" + cafe_bar_restaurant + '\'' +
                ", child_keeping='" + child_keeping + '\'' +
                ", clothes_laundry='" + clothes_laundry + '\'' +
                ", conference_rooms='" + conference_rooms + '\'' +
                ", dinner='" + dinner + '\'' +
                ", doctor_support='" + doctor_support + '\'' +
                ", elevator='" + elevator + '\'' +
                ", hair_dryer='" + hair_dryer + '\'' +
                ", in_room_safebox='" + in_room_safebox + '\'' +
                ", iron_ironing_board='" + iron_ironing_board + '\'' +
                ", minibar='" + minibar + '\'' +
                ", newspaper_delivery='" + newspaper_delivery + '\'' +
                ", parking='" + parking + '\'' +
                ", private_bath='" + private_bath + '\'' +
                ", reception_24='" + reception_24 + '\'' +
                ", room_service='" + room_service + '\'' +
                ", soundproof_walls='" + soundproof_walls + '\'' +
                ", wifi='" + wifi + '\'' +
                ", uid='" + uid + '\'' +
                ", user_reviews=" + user_reviews +
                '}';
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> houseObject = new HashMap<>();

        houseObject.put("city", city);
        houseObject.put("country", country);
        houseObject.put("description", description);
        houseObject.put("fotos", fotos);
        houseObject.put("hid", hid);
        houseObject.put("house_name", house_name);
        houseObject.put("langitude", langitude);
        houseObject.put("longitude", longitude);
        houseObject.put("mainFoto", mainFoto);
        houseObject.put("max_people", max_people);
        houseObject.put("price", price);
        houseObject.put("rating", rating);
        houseObject.put("postalCode", postalCode);
        houseObject.put("aircondition", aircondition);
        houseObject.put("balcony", balcony);
        houseObject.put("breakfast", breakfast);
        houseObject.put("cafe_bar_restaurant", cafe_bar_restaurant);
        houseObject.put("child_keeping", child_keeping);
        houseObject.put("clothes_laundry", clothes_laundry);
        houseObject.put("conference_rooms", conference_rooms);
        houseObject.put("dinner", dinner);
        houseObject.put("doctor_support", doctor_support);
        houseObject.put("elevator", elevator);
        houseObject.put("hair_dryer", hair_dryer);
        houseObject.put("in_room_safebox", in_room_safebox);
        houseObject.put("iron_ironing_board", iron_ironing_board);
        houseObject.put("minibar", minibar);
        houseObject.put("newspaper_delivery", newspaper_delivery);
        houseObject.put("parking", parking);
        houseObject.put("private_bath", private_bath);
        houseObject.put("reception_24", reception_24);
        houseObject.put("room_service", room_service);
        houseObject.put("soundproof_walls", soundproof_walls);
        houseObject.put("wifi", wifi);
        houseObject.put("uid", uid);
        houseObject.put("user_reviews", user_reviews);

        return houseObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this code

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;

 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("HOUSES").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                Houses model = new Houses(map.get("key_name"), map.get("key_name"),......);

                adapter.addItem(model);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(FetchData.this, "Something went wrong -> " + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```