# Issue in Retriving Data from Firebase : com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.ArrayList to String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm new to firebase and was trying to access a data from Firebase Realtime Database in android.

this is the data:
[image: MY FIREBASE DATA]

And below is the code

package com.manju.wista.fb_database;

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.GenericTypeIndicator;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference dbr;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BUSES_DATA/0");

        dbr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>>() {};
                Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator );

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),map.get("origin") , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }
}
```

When i run the code with

```
dbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BUSES_DATA/0"); 
or
dbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BUSES_DATA/1");
```

i get error

if i run with

```
dbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BUSES_DATA/2");
```

it Toasts the value

.. can anyone please help

Comment: Currently the firebase data has 0,1,2 nodes. i have 2000+ such nodes in actual real data

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153592/firebase-database-failed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-util-arraylist-to-string

Comment: @GastónSaillén : there is no accepted answer to it. please check

Comment: Answer below. For future questions please include the actual JSON as text (instead of a picture), which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to extract a `Map<String, String>` from the snapshot.

If you listen to `BUSES_DATA/2` this works, because each property under `BUSES_DATA/2` has a simple string value.

If you listen to `BUSES_DATA/0` or `BUSES_DATA/1` this fails, since some of the child nodes there are not simple strings. Specifically, the `BUSES_DATA/*/json_content` is a nested JSON object. Since a nested JSON object is not a string, the database raises an error when you ask it to convert it.

Once solution is to extract a `Map<String, Object>` from those snapshots. You'll find that in the first two child nodes that map then contains a key `json_content`, which contains another `Map<String, Object>` as its value.